# How to fix an ugly fraction with exponent?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, fractions, output

Here's a simple fraction that I find extremely ugly.  What could I do to get a better looking result (without using a negative exponent) ?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

TEST
\begin{equation}
    a(t) = \frac{g}{\bigl(1 + (g t / c)^2 \bigr)^{\frac{3}{2}}}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

Of course, I could use `3/2` instead of `\frac{3}{2}`, but I believe the result is worst.  I tried `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle` for the bottom part of the fraction, but the exponent is still creating the trouble.  So what would you do to get a better looking fraction with its pesky exponent, without writing everything at the numerator with a negative exponent?

Comment: There's no way to remove that white space, because the exponent is higher than the parenthesis: this is exactly why you should use `3/2`. Lowering the exponent would be ***much*** worse.

Comment: @SandyG, the second line of my question is excluding this option.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't see that.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of suggestions

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

TEST
\begin{equation}
    a(t) = \frac{g}{\bigl(1 + (g t / c)^2 \bigr)^{\frac{3}{2}}}.
\end{equation}

TEST2
\begin{equation}
    a(t) = \frac{g}{(1 + (g t / c)^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}.
\end{equation}


TEST3
\begin{equation}
    a(t) = \frac{g}{(1 + (g t / c)^2)^{\scriptscriptstyle\frac{3}{2}}}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just found that smashing the "big" parenthesis helps a lot.  The double same-sized parenthesis isn't good looking, in my opinion.  You could add the smashing option as a TEST4.

Comment: @Cham I wondered about smash, but I don't think I'd ever use big delimiters here irrespective of the fraction and superscript.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this hack with `bigstrut` will befit you?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\newcommand{\mybigstrut}[1] {{\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{#1}\bigstrut[b]}}

\begin{document}

TEST

\begin{equation}
    a(t) = \frac{g_{\mybigstrut{5pt}}}{\bigl(1 + (g t / c)^2 \bigr)^{\!\frac{3}{2}}}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to move the exponent out from the denominator and reposition it accordingly.  I used `\!` to move it left a bit, and then either `raisebox` to lower it by trial and error or `genfrac` to have the exponent in a phantom denominator.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\text{original: }&a(t) = \frac{g}{\bigl(1 + (g t / c)^2 \bigr)^{\frac{3}{2}}}.\\
\text{raisebox: }&a(t) = \frac{g}{\bigl(1 + (g t / c)^2 \bigr)}\!\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\scriptstyle\frac{3}{2}$}.\\
\text{genfrac: }&a(t) = \frac{g}{\bigl(1 + (g t / c)^2 \bigr)}\!\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{0}{}{{}^{\frac{3}{2}}}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: pdf output]